# Getting text from paragraph, after clicking and displaying an image

Tags: javascript, html, css

My html looks like that:

```
 <div class="row g-0 align-items-center wow fadeInUp galle" style="margin-top: 20px;  display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;" data-wow-delay=".25s">
      <div class="modal-img">
        <img class="full-img" src="#" alt="pop">
        <p class="caption" style="font-size: 50px;color: white;"></p>
      </div>
      <div class="card aluminiumCard" id="aluminium" style="width: 18rem;">
        <img id="imggene" src="assets\images\a.png" class="card-img-top alhigh" alt="..." >
        <div class="card-body imgal">
          <p class="card-text" style="font-size: 22px; text-align: center;font-weight: bold; color: white;">Text 1</p>
          <p class="img-text">Text genesuis </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card aluminiumCard" style="width: 18rem;">
        <img src="assets\images\2.png"  class="card-img-top alhigh" alt="..." >
        <div class="card-body imgal">
          <p class="card-text" style="font-size: 22px; text-align: center;font-weight: bold; color: white;">Image 2</p>
          <p class="img-text">Text 2</p>
        </div>
      </div>
   </div>
```

What I am trying to do is to click on image and forward the `src` to the img with `fullimg` class, which is displayed in the middle of the screen. I have figured out this part, but I am struggling with getting the data from the paragraph with class `img-text` and forwarding it to the paragraph with `caption` class, which is also displayed in the middle of the screen under the image.

Here's my javascript:

```
  const modalimg = document.querySelector(".modal-img");
  const previews = document.querySelectorAll(".galle img");
  const original = document.querySelector(".full-img");
  const imgText = document.querySelector(".caption");
  const Tests = document.querySelectorAll(".galle .img-text");

  previews.forEach(preview => {
    preview.addEventListener('click', () =>{
     modalimg.classList.add("open");
     original.classList.add("open");
     const originalSrc = preview.getAttribute('src');
  
    original.src = originalSrc;
      Tests.forEach(test => {
      const data = test.innerText;
      console.log(data);
     });
    
    })
  })

  modalimg.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    if(e.target.classList.contains('modal-img')){
      modalimg.classList.remove('open');
     original.classList.remove("open");
    }
   })
  })();
```

I was trying to get the `innerText` from `img-text` class and print that in the console just to test it, but it displays the `innerText` from all paragraphs with the same class.

[image]

What should I do, to get the `innerText` just from the card, that image is clicked on?

Comment: You need a way to identify the correct text to display. As you've already discovered, using `e.target` in your click event listener, returns you the element that initiated the event. You can work with that if you want to. Like going to its parent element, followed by going to the correct child element. Like `e.target.parentElement.children[1].children[1].children[1]`. Which translates to: `.modal-img > parent div > 2nd element inside parent div > 2nd element inside the resulting div > 2nd element inside the final resulting div` which is the `<p class="img-text"` element.

Answer (score 0):

There are also sibling selectors you can use that take advantage of relative positioning.  But be mindful of the html tags, adding or removing elements can break the assignments.

Alternatively you can add `data-*` attributes to the image and not have to worry about finding html tags at all.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
  const previews = document.querySelectorAll(".galle img");
  const original = document.querySelector(".full-img");
  const imgText = document.querySelector(".caption");
  const imgText2 = document.querySelector(".caption2");

  previews.forEach((e) => {
    e.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
      original.src = e.target.src;
      imgText.innerText = e.target.nextElementSibling.querySelector(".img-text").innerText;

      // OR by data-* attribute
      imgText2.innerText = e.target.dataset.description;
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.card-text {
  font-size: 22px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="row g-0 align-items-center wow fadeInUp galle" style="margin-top: 20px;  display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;" data-wow-delay=".25s">
  <div class="modal-img">
    <img class="full-img" src="#" alt="pop">
    <p class="caption" style="font-size: 20px;"></p>
    <p class="caption2"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="card aluminiumCard" id="aluminium" style="width: 18rem;">
    <img id="imggene" src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/100" 
      class="card-img-top alhigh" alt="..." 
      data-description="Text genesuis">
    <div class="card-body imgal">
      <p class="card-text">Text 1</p>
      <p class="img-text">Text genesuis</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card aluminiumCard" style="width: 18rem;">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/2/100" 
      class="card-img-top alhigh" alt="..." 
      data-description="Text 2">
    <div class="card-body imgal">
      <p class="card-text">Image 2</p>
      <p class="img-text">Text 2</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```